# Reusing the pointer to a structure in a for loop

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++, in fact very new to programming. I'm writing a code to solve 2D Navier-Stokes equation. Part of my code involves using a structure to allocate values to a PETSc object. The structure is needed for temporary calculations, just to assign the values to the PETSc object.
In order to do that, I'm using 'bodyVel' pointer, I allocate memory, perform calculations and de-allocate it. The program runs fine for 'j=0', when the j is incremented, the program crashes.

```
void function();

int main()
{   
function();

return 0;
}

void function()
{

     int b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  //values to be assigned to the PETSc object
     int c[5] = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

     int g[5] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14}; //(globalIndexMapping) indices where the values need to be assigned, index of the PETSc object starts from 10 (say)



    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)  //This is the outer time loop
    {
        typedef struct{
        int ub, vb;
        }bodyVelocity;  

        bodyVelocity *bodyVel;

        std::cout<<"This is iteration \t"<<j<<"\n";
        bodyVel = new bodyVelocity[5];
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {   
           int k = g[i];
           bodyVel[k].ub = b[i];
           bodyVel[k].vb = c[i];
           std::cout<<i<<"\t"<<bodyVel[k].ub<<"\t"<<bodyVel[k].vb<<"\t"<<"\n";
        }
    //values to the PETSc object is assigned here

        delete[] bodyVel;
    }

}
```

Here is the output from valgrind

```
==12248== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12248== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12248== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12248== Command: ./a.out
==12248== 
This is iteration   0
==12248== Invalid write of size 4
==12248==    at 0x4008AA: function() (in /home/shreenidhi/Desktop/a.out)
==12248==    by 0x4007BC: main (in /home/shreenidhi/Desktop/a.out)
==12248==  Address 0x5a03090 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==12248== 
==12248== Invalid write of size 4
==12248==    at 0x4008C3: function() (in /home/shreenidhi/Desktop/a.out)
==12248==    by 0x4007BC: main (in /home/shreenidhi/Desktop/a.out)
==12248==  Address 0x5a03094 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==12248== 
==12248== Invalid read of size 4
==12248==    at 0x4008D3: function() (in /home/shreenidhi/Desktop/a.out)
==12248==    by 0x4007BC: main (in /home/shreenidhi/Desktop/a.out)
==12248==  Address 0x5a03094 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==12248== 
==12248== Invalid read of size 4
==12248==    at 0x4008E3: function() (in /home/shreenidhi/Desktop/a.out)
==12248==    by 0x4007BC: main (in /home/shreenidhi/Desktop/a.out)
==12248==  Address 0x5a03090 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==12248== 
0   1   6   
1   2   7   
2   3   8   
3   4   9   
4   5   10  
This is iteration   1
--12248-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--12248-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x605A03088;  sp: 0x408bdae00

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal
==12248==    at 0x38058236: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==12248==    by 0x38021ADC: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==12248==    by 0x38021D2D: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==12248==    by 0x380902A7: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==12248==    by 0x3809F7D5: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==12248==    at 0x4C2AC27: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12248==    by 0x400876: function() (in /home/shreenidhi/Desktop/a.out)
==12248==    by 0x4007BC: main (in /home/shreenidhi/Desktop/a.out)
```

Impossible happened? What is valgrind complaining about?

I saw a lot of posts addressing the problem, but couldn't find the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!!!

Comment: Ain't you going for k=5 in here `bodyVel[k].ub = b[i]`?

Comment: Couple of issues: 1) what is the purpose of j? 2) k=i+1 causes k to be 5 which is the 6th element of a 5 element array (memory corruption)

Comment: Either make bodyvel a regular array or a vector.

Comment: Sorry! I edited the code now. I have a global map of indices for the PETSc object. Please have a look at the new code and the error.
P.S I over simplified the code when I put 'k=i+1', mistake indeed. I need the values at the mapping indices.

Comment: Can you post the actual code? You've made things worse. The only correct values that k can have are 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

On the last iteration of the inner loop, `i == 4` and `k == 5`.

This means that `bodyVel[k]` is `bodyVel[5]`, which is the 6th of the 5 element array created by `new bodyVelocity[5]` (and thus is beyond the end of the array, meaning that the dereference has undefined behaviour).

This is the problem that valgrind is warning you about.

Comment: Sorry! I edited the code now. I have a global map of indices for the PETSc object. Please have a look at the new code and the error. P.S I over simplified the code when I put 'k=i+1', mistake indeed. I need the values at the mapping indices.

Comment: Now it's even worse. `k = g[i]` is one of `{10, 11, 12, 13, 14}`. **None** of those are within the bounds of a `5` element array!

Comment: Have you tried `std::cout<<i<<"\t"<<bodyVel[i].ub<<"\t"<<bodyVel[i].vb<<"\t"<<"\n";` ?

Answer (score 0):

In C++, array index starts from 0. There is no need to do 'int k = i+1;', You could use i itself in the loop.